# Обмен сообщениями между вкладками браузера | BroadcastChannel API

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью **JavaScript** передавать данные между вкладками и окнами браузера или фреймами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для это цели стоит использовать `BroadcastChannel API`. Между страницами, где будет создан объект `BroadcastChannel` и указано единое имя канала, можно обмениваться данными. Данные можно передавать между вкладками, окнами браузера или фреймами:

```
// Создаём новый канал для обмена сообщениями:
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('my_channel')

// Отправляем сообщение:
bc.postMessage('postMessage')

// Получаем сообщение от других вкладок:
bc.onMessage = (e) => console.log(e)
```

`BroadcastChannel` работает в новых браузерах. Для IE и прочих можно использовать [полифил](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broadcast-channel).